# mysql to vb.net command

Tags: mysql, vb.net

please help me on this code
when i run this code i having a error " invalid attempt to read when reader is close"

```
            q = "select * from test.table1"

            com = New MySqlCommand(q, con)

            rs = com.ExecuteReader

            While rs.Read

                Dim ln = rs.GetInt64("id1")
                Dim fn = rs.GetString("name")

                If fn = TextBox1.Text Then
                    rs.Close()<this line having error>

                    f1 = "INSERT INTO test.table2(id2,fname,Mname,name)VALUE('" & "null" & "','" & TextBox2.Text & "','" & TextBox3.Text & "','" & Val(ln) & "')"
                    com = New MySqlCommand(f1, con)
                    com.ExecuteNonQuery()
             End If

            End While

            con.Close()

            rs.Dispose()
            MsgBox("successfully inserted the data")
```

Comment: What happen after you enter for the first time inside the if block?

Comment: the first query run but when i inserted data in the table i having trouble that the rs = mydatareader should be close in order for the second to execute

Comment: also i have two table table table1 compose of id1,name,age and second table name table2  have id2,fname,mname,id1 where table1.id1 should be equal to table2.id1 where it have relation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you enter the if block you close the `MySqlDataReader` because you need to run an insert command, but when a connection is busy serving a DataReader cannot be used to serve another command. However the code continues and the next loop is executed. At this point if you try to read using the previous variable you get the error because the MySqlReader has been closed at the previous loop.

You could fix the problem opening a second connection using the connectionstring from the first connection. This seems to be the required path with `MySql .NET Adapter` because it doesn't support the `MultipleActiveResultSets` keyword in the connection string like SqlServer

```
While rs.Read

    Dim ln = rs.GetInt64("id1")
    Dim fn = rs.GetString("name")

    If fn = TextBox1.Text Then
        f1 = "INSERT INTO ........"
        Using con2 = new MySqlConnection(con.ConnectionString)
            con2.Open()
            com = New MySqlCommand(f1, con2)
            com.ExecuteNonQuery()
        End Using
    End If

End While
```

Comment: when i try you example i have error occurred  the connection must be valid open and i also declare con2 as mysqlconnection

Comment: Yes, forgot it, added now

Comment: No need to have an explicit declaration. It is inferred automatically from the new MySqlConnection. It is used just inside the if and closed and disposed at the End Using statement

Comment: A part from this, I really suggest you to look at Parameterized Query and Sql Injection. Search on your favourite search engine and you will find interesting tips to improve your INSERT query.